# Using PyCharm's remote debugger on remote machines inside docker

Tags: docker, pycharm

Pycharm's remote debugger on a **local** Docker container works as expected (2016.1 and later).  All of our development is now done on the cloud where our data resides and Data Loss Prevention mechanisms are deployed.  So no code is being developed on laptops.  Is it possible to use Pycharm's debugger attached to a docker container on a remote server to step through and debug code?

Comment: Have you tried configuring PyCharms remote debugger with the address of the remote machine (in place of localhost / 0.0.0.0)? With the assumption the ports and securities allow it this would be my first avenue to explore.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not supported out of the box, but there is a workaround. See the description of this feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33489

Note: it doesn't work for docker-compose.